# Execução definida no pom não é realizada ao publicar projeto no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Eu defini no POM do meu projeto o seguinte plugin no build:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>install-package</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>projeto.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}/public</outputDirectory>
            <includes>foo/**/*</includes>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Quando eu gero o EAR utilizando o Maven (mvn clean install, por exemplo) ele executa o que está definido no POM (a pasta foo e seus subdiretórios é criada no EAR). Porém quando eu adiciono o projeto a ser iniciado no Jboss dentro do Eclipse essa execução não é feita (a pasta "foo" não é criada no deployments do Jboss)...

Há alguma configuração a ser feita no Eclipse para que todos os recursos sejam sincronizados? Não quero ficar construindo o pacote pois vou perder muito tempo esperando o build, visto que no Eclipse qualquer modificação que eu faço em minhas páginas já é sincronizada no servidor de aplicação.